# Raku: How to make read STDIN raw data?

Tags: encoding, stdin, raku

How could I write this Perl5 code in Raku?

```
my $return = binmode STDIN, ':raw';
if ( $return ) {
    print "\e[?1003h";
}
```

---

Comment to cuonglm's answer.

I am already using `read`:

```
my $termios := Term::termios.new(fd => 1).getattr;
$termios.makeraw;
$termios.setattr(:DRAIN);

sub ReadKey {
    return $*IN.read( 1 ).decode();
}

sub mouse_action {
    my $c1 = ReadKey();
    return if ! $c1.defined;
    if $c1 eq "\e" {
        my $c2 = ReadKey();
        return if ! $c2.defined;
        if $c2 eq '[' {
            my $c3 = ReadKey();
            if $c3 eq 'M' {
                my $event_type = ReadKey().ord - 32;
                my $x          = ReadKey().ord - 32;
                my $y          = ReadKey().ord - 32;
                return [ $event_type, $x, $y ];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But with STDIN set to UTF-8 I get errors with `$x` or `$y` greater than 127 - 32:

```
Malformed UTF-8 at ...
```

Comment: utf-8 is a variable-length encoding that isn't binary-safe; depending on what you're trying to do, either use `.decode('latin1')`, or just keep the numeric values and replace things like `$c3 eq 'M'` with `$c3 == 'M'.ord`

Comment: I think the only reason your code doesn't work right now is that you use .decode, as Christoph suggests, you can use latin1 to get a String that won't ever fail no matter what data you get in. Otherwise, I suggest you just return $*IN.read(1)[0] to get only the single byte value out.

Comment: Now I have three possibilities. I've already tried the `latin1`-solution. Maybe I stick to it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [method read()](http://doc.perl6.org/type/IO::Handle#method_read) from [class IO::Handle](http://doc.perl6.org/type/IO::Handle) to perform binary reading:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/perl6

use v6;

my $result = $*IN.read(512);
$*OUT.write($result);
```

Then:

```
$ printf '1\0a\n' | perl6 test.p6 | od -t x1
0000000 31 00 61 0a
0000004
```

You don't need *binmode* in Perl 6, since when you can decide to read data as binary or as text, depend on what methods you use.